# could not load main class netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

```
public class Sequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int limit=20;
        int sum=0;
        int a=0;
        int b=1;

        while(sum<limit)
        {
            sum=a+b;
            a=b;
            b=sum;
        }
    }
}
```

My Netbeans was working fine when I was using jdk 1.8.0.65 earlier but due do some reason I lost my data, I installed jdk 1.8.0.73 then and now my every program on Netbeans shows this error:

> run: Error: Could not find or load main class sequence.Sequence
>   C:\Users\owais\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I googled the problem and updated the netbeans_jdk path in netbeans.config file but still it does not work.
I am new to programming I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: please clean the project and it will create the .class files automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuall, when you click the "Run" button on top of the netbeans window, it only run the application's main class . but this Sequence class is not the main class of the project most probably. for this case to run this class you have to right click on Sequence class editor and select Run or Run as menu. Then this class will be executed on separate console, I hope this will work ..

Comment: Yes i figured that out,Thank you buddy.

Comment: yes, sequence class was not the main class so i opened the project property and selected sequence as the main class there and it solved the problem.

Comment: however it was'nt executed on seperate console.

Answer (score 1):

I have been a victim of this problem, but the project I was working on was a bit large and I happen to use multiple Jpanel under one JFrame to develop the project so the code was over 15,000 lines of codes. So this seem to happen when I build the project, the code were scanned but because of the long code under the main class, it fail to reach the end of the code and raise the fail to load the main class. This is how I solve the problem using the Netbeans IDE:

1. Remove unnecessary components and codes to reduce the code size.
2. Right Click on the project name, then click refactor and rename the project name.
3. Also rename both the classes and jframes in the project.
4. Click Run Then Click Clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

If main class is correctly specify, try this.

Two problems I can identify:

1. File name has special characters. Remove those special characters.
2. Folder where the project was located has special characters. Remove those special characters too.

These will solve the problem:
Error: Could not find or load main class Classes.Test
/..../...../Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)